# Error while trying to install app on odoo 15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

This is the error message I get when I try to install the app
This is the error message I get when I try to install the app

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 687, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 348, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 916, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 535, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1346, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1334, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 464, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 451, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-74>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 486, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 603, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 87, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 474, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 363, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 179, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/modules/module.py", line 396, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/addons/pragtech_whatsapp_base/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import controller
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/addons/pragtech_whatsapp_base/controller/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import main
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/addons/pragtech_whatsapp_base/controller/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import phonenumbers
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'phonenumbers'
```

I tried to install a terminal app on Odoo and it showed me this error

This is the error message I get when I try to install the app
This is the error message I get when I try to install the app
This is the error message I get when I try to install the app

Comment: ```phonenumbers``` python library is not installed; you need to install it using terminal. ```sudo pip install phonenumbers```

Answer (score 1):

The module uses [phonenumbers](https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/) to sanitize country mobile.

Installing the `phonenumbers` should fix that error:

```
pip install phonenumbers
```